# Hebrews 13:5 quotes God saying he would never leave nor forsake us. Where is the original quote?

Tags: hebrews, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, reference-request

> Let your conversation be without covetousness; and be content with
> such things as ye have: **for he hath said,** *I will never leave thee, nor
> forsake thee.* (Hebrews 13:5, KJV)

The text indicates that God (referenced in prior verse) has said this.  But where in the Bible is it recorded?  What seems to be a prayer *asking* for God to not leave nor forsake us can be found:

> The LORD our God be with us, as he was with our fathers: *let him not
> leave us, nor forsake us:* (1 Kings 8:57, KJV)

...but making a request and making a declarative statement are not the same thing.

Wherein, therefore, can Hebrews 13:5 be shown to be true?

Comment: _He doth not fail thee nor forsake thee; fear not, nor be affrighted.'_ Deuteronomy 31:8 Young's Literal Translation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heb 13:5 is a partial quote from Deut 31:8.

"And the LORD, He is the One who goes before you. He will be with you, He will not leave you nor forsake you; do not fear nor be dismayed.”

Comment: What version is that?  I was not finding that because KJV has it as: "And the LORD, he it is that doth go before thee; he will be with thee, he will not **fail** thee, neither forsake thee: fear not, neither be dismayed." (Deuteronomy 31:8, KJV)

Comment: That Is from the NKJV

Comment: Thank you!  Now I need to add Deuteronomy 31:8 as a cross-reference for Hebrews 13:5.  It seems odd that the cross-references in my Bible missed it.

Comment: NOTE: Having found it, Deuteronomy 31:6 also has similar phrasing: "Be strong and of a good courage, fear not, nor be afraid of them: for the LORD thy God, he it is that doth go with thee; **he will not fail thee, nor forsake thee.**"